# find value or NA if the key does not exist in dict of dicts

Tags: python

```
  results = {
    "IPSEC-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 5974,
      "kpps": 2114,
      "rate": 31.56,
      "qfp": 86,
      "label": "BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843"
    },
    "IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 5913,
      "kpps": 2065,
      "rate": 31.223,
      "qfp": 90,
      "label": "BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843"
    },
    "IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_SNAT_ZBFW-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 2640,
      "kpps": 922,
      "rate": 13.942,
      "qfp": 85,
      "label": "BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843"
    },
    "IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_TNAT-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 5884,
      "kpps": 2055,
      "rate": 31.067,
      "qfp": 95,
      "label": "BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843"
    },
    "IPSEC_MCAST-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 3330,
      "kpps": 1163,
      "rate": 35.164,
      "qfp": 64,
      "label": "BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843"
    },
    "IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_MCAST-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 3407,
      "kpps": 1190,
      "rate": 36.002,
      "qfp": 87,
      "label": "BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843"
    },
    "IPSECV6-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 5673,
      "kpps": 1919,
      "rate": 29.904,
      "qfp": 25,
      "label": "BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843"
    },
    "IPSECV6_QOSV6_DPI_FNF-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 5768,
      "kpps": 1951,
      "rate": 30.403,
      "qfp": 38,
      "label": "BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843"
    }
  }
```

I have a string `the_feature` which maps to to the keys in the above dict (example `IPSEC-IMIX`) and I want to get either the `throughput` or "NA" if the feature does not exist.

Tried the below but it does not work when an inexistent `the_feature` is used.

```
answer = results[the_feature]["throughput"] if results[the_feature]["throughput"] else "NA"


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\code\api_server_imix.py", line 1113, in get_results
    item["release_speed"] = release_obj.results[the_feature].get("throughput", "NA")


        value = super().__getitem__(key)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'IPSEC-1400'
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? what are the results?

Comment: Why not use `.get()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more minimal example and maybe what you're looking for. The trick is you just need to check to see if the key exists or not, and in your example it always existed -- plus, in your code you don't check for the key's existence but rather whether it is true or false (most values of most types return as true).

```
results = {
    "IPSEC-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 5974
    },
    "IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 5913
    },
    "IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_SNAT_ZBFW-IMIX": {
      "throughput": 2640
    },
    "NO_THROUGHPUT": {
      "other": 0
    }
}
features = results.keys()
for the_feature in features:
    answer = results[the_feature]["throughput"] if "throughput" in results[the_feature] else "NA"
    print(answer)

"""prints
5974
5913
2640
NA
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to provide a default result when a key is not present in the dictionary (instead of getting a `KeyError`), and chain them together:

```
answer = results.get(the_feature,{}).get("throughput","NA")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to control the source of the throughput, you could use a dict comprehension with get():

```
output = {x:results[x].get('throughput','NA') for x in results}
```

Returning:

```
{'IPSEC-IMIX': 5974,
 'IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF-IMIX': 5913,
 'IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_SNAT_ZBFW-IMIX': 2640,
 'IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_TNAT-IMIX': 5884,
 'IPSEC_MCAST-IMIX': 3330,
 'IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_MCAST-IMIX': 3407,
 'IPSECV6-IMIX': 5673,
 'IPSECV6_QOSV6_DPI_FNF-IMIX': 5768}
```

Or if you only want the values as list:

```
 output.values()
```

Returning:

```
dict_values([5974, 5913, 2640, 5884, 3330, 3407, 5673, 5768])
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not your solution by itself but the fact that you don't check wether the key exist beforehand

Keeping somewhat your code, you could do this to modify it and make it work

```
if the_feature in results:

    answer = results[the_feature]["throughput"] if "throughput" in results[the_feature] else "NA"
```

Comment: Indeed, I modified the code, copied the post too fast